# UIWebView Link Clicks Inside Scroll View

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am facing an interesting issue. I have HTML data that I obtain from a Web service that I display inside the UIWebView and I want to open up hyperlinks in Safari when a user taps on the link.

The code I have works great for any links that are visible immediately within the Web View. I have a scroll on the View and links that are below the visible area (i.e. links that I have to scroll to) do not work when I tap them at all.

Please note that I'm disabling all scrollbars in the WebView using logic like so:

```
DescriptionWebView = new UIWebView(new RectangleF(0, separator.Frame.Bottom + 1, 320, 140));
        DescriptionWebView.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.All;
        DescriptionWebView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        DescriptionWebView.Delegate = new PlanDescriptionWebViewDelegate(this);


        foreach(UIView subview in DescriptionWebView.Subviews)
        {                   
                    if(subview is UIScrollView)
                        (subview as UIScrollView).ScrollEnabled = false;
        }
```

And I'm resizing the WebView based on the content size using logic inside of a delegate like so:

```
 public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
                 {
                            NSUrl url = request.Url;
                            if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.Other)
                            {
                                      if(url.Scheme.ToString().Equals("ready"))
                                      {

                                                 float contentHeight = Convert.ToInt32(url.Host);
                                                 if(contentHeight < _infoView.DescriptionWebView.Frame.Height)
                                                            contentHeight = _infoView.DescriptionWebView.Frame.Height;
                                                 RectangleF scrollViewFrame = _infoView.ScrollView.Frame;
                                                 RectangleF descriptionViewFrame = _infoView.DescriptionWebView.Frame;
                                                 BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                                                 {
                                                            _infoView.DescriptionWebView.Frame = new RectangleF(descriptionViewFrame.X, descriptionViewFrame.Y, descriptionViewFrame.Width, contentHeight + 10);
                                                            //_infoView.ScrollView.ContentSize =  new SizeF(scrollViewFrame.Size.Width, contentHeight + scrollViewFrame.Y + scrollViewFrame.Height - descriptionViewFrame.Height);
                                                            _infoView.ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(scrollViewFrame.Size.Width, contentHeight + scrollViewFrame.Height + 20 - descriptionViewFrame.Height);
                                                 });
                                                 return false;       
                                      }

                            } else if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
                            {
                                      UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
                                      return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                 }
```

I am completely at a loss. Why would links on the top within view work, and the ones at the bottom where I have to scroll won't?

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: Are you able to click the links which are hidden from view by scrolling, when you disable the resizing code?